# Why are ranges split into inclusive and exclusive?

Tags: arrays, database, list, data-structures, range

Meaning, is it possible for a program to lose functionality simply because all its range calls were converted from inclusive to exclusive( fo example, <1 to 5> inclusive converted to <1 to 6> exclusive) or vice versa?

I'm just wondering if there any practical reasons for having both types, or is it strictly according to programmer preference.

Comment: When dealing with continuous domains like real numbers, inclusive and exclusive boundaries aren't interchangeable.

Comment: Oh, I see. So an exclusive range of real numbers from 1 to 5 has no clear end boundary (4.9999999999...etc).  Makes sense. Thanks.